# Make Appium reset driver and app after every test

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, appium

Hi I'm using your project https://github.com/rajatt95/MasterAppiumFramework_BDD for testing but I want to modify it so it resets the app and driver after every test instead of every class. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks that you need to add call of DriverManager.getDriver().resetApp() method in quit() method of Hooks class.